# How to compute the first three terms of the Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

Consider the equation ${\epsilon}(x^{5} + \cos(x)) + x^{2} - 1 = 0$. When $\epsilon = 0, x_{0} = 1$ is a solution. Compute the first three terms of the Taylor expansion $$x = x_{0} + {\epsilon}x_{1} + {\epsilon}^{2}x_{2} + ... $$ centered at $\epsilon = 0$ with $x(0) = 1$.

how to compute this expansion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to do some inserting. First of all, insert the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ with respect to $x$:
$$
\epsilon(x^5 + 1 -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \cdots) + x^2 - 1 = 0
$$
Next, we insert the Taylor expansion of $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$:
$$
\epsilon\left((x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2x_2 + \cdots)^5\vphantom{\frac{2^2}{2}} \right.\\+ 1 - \frac{(x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2x_2 + \cdots)^2}{2}
\left. + \frac{(x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2x_2 + \cdots)^4}{24} - \cdots\right)\\
+ (x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2x_2 + \cdots)^2 - 1 = 0
$$
Now sort things by order of $\epsilon$ (note that since the parenthesis is multiplied by $\epsilon$, everything inside it has its degree upped by one):
$$
\epsilon^0: \quad x_0^2 - 1 = 0 \implies x = \pm 1
$$
We're told specifically to use the solution $x_0 = 1$, so we'll do that. Moving on:
$$
\epsilon^1:\quad \epsilon(x_0^5 + 1 - \frac{x_0^2}{2} + \frac{x_0^4}{24} - \cdots) + 2\epsilon x_0x_1 = 0\\
1 + \cos(1) + 2x_1 = 0\\
x_1 = -\frac{1+\cos(1)}{2} \approx -0.77
$$
and, finally
$$
\epsilon^2: \quad\epsilon(5\epsilon x_0x_1 - \frac{2\epsilon x_0x_1}{2} + \frac{4\epsilon x_0x_1}{24} - \cdots) + \epsilon^2x_1^2 + 2\epsilon^2x_0x_2 = 0\\
5x_1 - \sin(x_1) + x_1^2 + 2x_2 = 0\\
x_2 = \frac{\sin(x_1) - x_1(5+x_1)}{2} \approx 1.28
$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must expand $\cos x$ around $x=1$. As we are interested only to terms up to $\epsilon^2$ we need only retain the first term (because $\cos x$ is multiplied by $\epsilon$):
$$
\cos x=\cos1-\sin1(x-1)+\dots
$$
Substitute that into your equation and substitute there also $x = 1 + {\epsilon}x_{1} + {\epsilon}^{2}x_{2} + ... $, retaining only terms up to $\epsilon^2$. Your equation then becomes:
$$
\epsilon (1 + 2 x_1 + \cos1 ) + 
\epsilon^2 (5 x_1 + x_1^2 + 2 x_2 - x_1 \sin1)+\dots=0.
$$
To find $x_1$ and $x_2$ just equate to zero the coefficients of $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^2$:
$$
1 + 2 x_1 + \cos1 =0
\quad\implies\quad
x_1=-{\cos1+1\over2}
$$
$$
5 x_1 + x_1^2 + 2 x_2 - x_1 \sin1 =0;
\quad\implies\quad
x_2=-{\cos1+1\over8}(2\sin1+\cos1-9).
$$